# SQL Computing a running total of an order by customer using self-join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, self-join, cumulative-sum

So I know this has been somewhat done to death, but I'm really struggling with it.  At work I have SQL Server 2008, and I've been asked to do a running total, so no windowed functions for me.  This means I have to do it the old school way, so to learn this, I'm using the AdventureWorks 2012 database and trying to do a running total on `totaldue` for each `salesorderid` by `customerid` in the sales.salesorderheader table.  Relevant columns are:

```
salesorderid int not null
customerid int not null
totaldue money not null
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
select soh1.salesorderid
, soh1.customerid
, soh1.totaldue
, sum(soh2.totaldue) 'running_total'
from sales.salesorderheader soh1
inner join sales.salesorderheader soh2 on soh1.totaldue <= soh2.totaldue
                                       and soh1.customerid = soh2.customerid
group by soh1.customerid, soh1.salesorderid, soh1.totaldue
order by soh1.customerid, soh1.salesorderid;
```

I get the following (first 10 rows):

```
salesorderid    customerid  totaldue    runningtotal
43793           11000       3756.989    3756.989
51522           11000       2587.8769   9115.1341
57418           11000       2770.2682   6527.2572
43767           11001       3729.364    3729.364
51493           11001       2674.0227   6403.3867
43736           11002       3756.989    3756.989
51238           11002       2535.964    8966.0143
53237           11002       2673.0613   6430.0503
43701           11003       3756.989    3756.989
51315           11003       2562.4508   8993.9155
57783           11003       2674.4757   6431.4647
```

I feel like I'm close - I notice that when there are only two sales orders for a given customerid, the running total computes correctly.  However when it's 3 or more, it goes to crap.

I looked at a break out of the join for customerid = 11000 to see why the second and third orderids (51522 and 57418) aren't computing correctly.  I ran the following code:

```
select soh1.salesorderid
, soh1.customerid
, soh1.totaldue
, soh2.salesorderid
, soh2.customerid
, soh2.totaldue
from sales.salesorderheader soh1
inner join sales.salesorderheader soh2 on soh1.totaldue <= soh2.totaldue
                                          and soh1.customerid = soh2.customerid
where soh1.customerid = 11000
order by soh1.customerid, soh1.salesorderid;
```

and I get this:

```
salesorderid  customerid  totaldue   salesorderid  customerid  totaldue
43793         11000       3756.989   43793         11000       3756.989
51522         11000       2587.8769  43793         11000       3756.989
51522         11000       2587.8769  51522         11000       2587.8769
**51522       11000       2587.8769  57418         11000       2770.2682**
57418         11000       2770.2682  57418         11000       2770.2682
57418         11000       2770.2682  43793         11000       3756.989
```

I can see that the issue in the 4th row, where it's bringing in a row that I don't want there, and then for salesorderid 57418 it's missing one row.  I suspect that the issue is with my join, but I can't figure out the logic that would bring in the right rows.

I've asked to be able to use SQL 2012 or later but no dice.  Please help!

Comment: dont you just have to group the sales order id and sales order id2 then sum its total due?

Comment: Not entirely following, can you give a code example?  I'm currently grouping by salesorderid1, not sure what grouping salesorderid2 would do.  If you mean group both as separate tables then add the results, I don't believe that would give me a running total.

Comment: you can also use **CROSS APPLY** for running totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should not your self-join be done on customer and salesorder id instead of totaldue? See the following:

```
select soh1.salesorderid
, soh1.customerid
, soh1.totaldue
, sum(soh2.totaldue) 'running_total'
from sales.salesorderheader soh1
inner join sales.salesorderheader soh2 on soh2.salesorderid <= soh1.salesorderid
                                   and soh2.customerid = soh1.customerid
group by soh1.customerid, soh1.salesorderid, soh1.totaldue
order by soh1.customerid, soh1.salesorderid;
```

Comment: You got it.  Can't believe I didn't see it!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try CTE

```
;with grouped as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY salesorderid) as groupId 
    from sales.salesorderheader
), cte as
(
    select *, totaldue as runningtotal from grouped where groupId = 1
    union all
    select grouped.*, grouped.totaldue + cte.runningtotal
    from grouped inner join cte on 
        grouped.groupId - 1 = cte.groupId 
        and grouped.customerid = cte.customerid
)
select * from cte order by customerid, salesorderid
```

Comment: Tried running this and it doesn't seem to calculate the running total

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:

```
select soh1.salesorderid
, soh1.customerid
, soh1.totaldue
,(select  sum(soh2.totaldue) from sales.salesorderheader soh2      
  where soh1.totaldue <= soh2.totaldue 
  and  soh1.customerid = soh2.customerid) as 'Running Totoal'
from sales.salesorderheader soh1
where soh1.customerid = 11000
order by soh1.customerid, soh1.salesorderid
```

Comment: This produces an identical result to my closest query above.  It correctly calculates a running total where there are only 2 sales to a given customerid, but once it's 3 or more it sums incorrectly given the sort order.